# Postgres Managing more than one one to many relationship in query

Tags: sql, postgresql, one-to-many

Context

I am writing an application that does a variation on the Vehicle Routing Problem. The application has routes, stops and driving directions for routes. I need to write a query for a view that combines all the relevant attributes for a route. Hence I need to join the routes table to multiple many to many relationships in a single query.

Query Details

There is the routes table, the route_stop_join table and the route directions table. The relationship between routes and stops is really many to many but we only need a list of stop ids, so suffices to consider the one to many relationship with the join table. The following query counts the sums n time where n is the number of stops:

```
select     r.id, 
           array_agg(j.stop_id) as stops, 
           sum(rd.time_elapsed) as total_time, 
           sum(rd.drive_distance) as total_distance 
from       routes_directions rd 
right join routes r 
on         rd.route_id = r.id 
left join  routes_stops_join j 
on         r.id = j.route_id 
group by   r.id;
```

I can do this using a subselect like this:

```
select rj.id, 
       rj.stops, 
       sum(rd.time_elapsed) as total_time, 
       sum(rd.drive_distance) as total_distance 
from   routes_directions rd 
right join (select r.id, 
                   array_agg(j.stop_id) as stops 
            from  routes r 
            left join routes_stops_join j 
            on r.id = j.route_id 
            group by r.id) rj 
on       rj.id = rd.route_id 
group by rj.id, rj.stops;
```

but I would like to see if there is a way to do this in a single query without subselects.

Comment: Left justified SQL!?! Do you really write like that, or is it a copy and paste problem - and you expect us to read it anyway.

Comment: @McNets, but I wrote my comment before your edit. It looks much better now!

Comment: ok, I've seen your comment after edit, it's a time travel issue. @jarlh

Comment: @McNets, I suppose you commited your edit while I was writing my comment. Should be a transaction failure, I suppose.

Comment: Maybe a table schema could help. At least prefix all fields with its alias.

Comment: Jeepers! I was just making it multiline so you wouldn't have to scroll horizontally, I use vim so I have to copy paste and format by hand. I usually take more time but it seems like such a simple thing. thanks to @McNets

Comment: @McNets I think I got them all. Sorry long day.

Comment: Can exists a route_direction without stops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as this query returns 99% of the information you need:

```
select     rd.id, 
           sum(rd.time_elapsed) as total_time, 
           sum(rd.drive_distance) as total_distance 
from       routes_directions rd 
group by   rd.id;
```

I'd suggest to use a subquery or a CTE, but using LEFT JOIN instead of RIGHT JOIN.

> ```
> create table routes(id int);
> insert into routes values (1),(2);
> create table routes_stops(route_id int, stop_id int);
> insert into routes_stops values (1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,3),(2,4);
> create table routes_directions(route_id int, dir_id int, time_elapsed int, drive_distance int);
> insert into routes_directions values (1,1,100,40),(1,2,60,60),(2,1,15,14),(2,3,20,30);
> ```

> ```
> select rj.id, 
>        rj.stops, 
>        sum(rd.time_elapsed) as total_time, 
>        sum(rd.drive_distance) as total_distance 
> from   routes_directions rd 
> left  join (select   r.id, 
>                      array_agg(j.stop_id) as stops 
>             from     routes r 
>             left     join routes_stops j 
>             on       r.id = j.route_id 
>             group by r.id) rj 
> on       rj.id = rd.route_id 
> group by rj.id, rj.stops;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | stops   | total_time | total_distance
> -: | :------ | ---------: | -------------:
>  2 | {1,3,4} |         35 |             44
>  1 | {1,2}   |        160 |            100
> ```

> ```
> with stp as
> (
>     select r.id, 
>            array_agg(j.stop_id) as stops 
>     from   routes r 
>     left   join routes_stops j 
>     on     r.id = j.route_id 
>     group  by r.id
> )
> select     rd.route_id,
>            stp.stops, 
>            sum(rd.time_elapsed) as total_time, 
>            sum(rd.drive_distance) as total_distance 
> from       routes_directions rd 
> left join  stp
> on         stp.id = rd.route_id
> group by   rd.route_id, stp.stops;
> ```
>
> ```
> route_id | stops   | total_time | total_distance
> -------: | :------ | ---------: | -------------:
>        1 | {1,2}   |        160 |            100
>        2 | {1,3,4} |         35 |             44
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=e6f634609d883617b153be445f4bdac2)*

Comment: This is prettier than a subselect but is it functionally different at all? It's certainly prettier!

Comment: On this question is it basically the same, you can have a look at execution plan to be sure.

Comment: CTE seems to be a little bit better, but obviously there is not data enough. http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=d13cd15c9e06f754e5c0cacf1d709a2d